# Get previous attribute value in Eloquent model event

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Is there a way to see the old/previous value of a model's attribute in its `saving` or `updating` event?

eg. Is something like the following possible:

```
User::updating(function($user)
{
    if ($user->username != $user->old->username) doSomething();
});
```

Answer (score 203, accepted):

Ok, I found this quite by chance, as it's not in the documentation at present...

There is a `getOriginal()` method available which returns an array of the original attribute values:

```
User::updating(function($user)
{
    if ($user->username != $user->getOriginal('username')) {
        doSomething();
    }

    // If you need multiple attributes you may use:
    // $originalAttributes = $user->getOriginal();
    // $originalUsername = $originalAttributes['username']; 
});
```

> Be careful, prior to Laravel 7 `getOriginal` ignores attribute type casting.

Comment: getOriginal has one parameter which is the name of the field you looking for.

Comment: Do you know if that returns the previous object or it returns the first value ever?

Comment: be carefult, it ignores the model type casting.

Comment: Do note that ever since Laravel 7.x, this method has been renamed to `getRawOriginal()`. See upgrade guide: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/upgrade

Comment: @RobinvanBaalen - I haven't tested it, but the new behaviour of getOriginal since Laravel 7 actually seems *more* desirable for doing these comparisons, as I expect the current attribute value has already had casting applied...

Comment: This is not working btw

Answer (score 49):

In Laravel 4.0 and 4.1, you can check with [isDirty() method](http://laravel.com/api/4.1/):

```
User::updating(function($user)
{
    if ($user->isDirty('username')){
        doSomething();
    }
});
```

Comment: Works in 5.2.39 too. Thanks Ola.

Comment: This doesn't get the previous value

Comment: still works like a peach in Laravel 9. Thanks!

Answer (score -5):

You could overload the methods, then call the parent method.

Comment: and now we can do it right here `class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider` in `boot` method.